# Convert into column using delimited PIPE in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, pipe

Present value

All (one column)

```
--

43 | 00043 | 22/09/2016 | Ooredoo - AuU TX | Raj singh
```

I want it should be in separate column like given below

```
ID  Key   Date       Company                   Owner 

43  00043 22/09/2016 Ooredoo - AuU TX         Raj singh
```

Comment: You mean all the values are stored in a column?

Comment: no, each values should be stored in different columns like for 43 its header is ID and key value should 00043 etc etc

Comment: I mean right now it's a single column.

Comment: yes, presently all the values are in one column with PIPE delimited. now i want to divide each values in different columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to do so and declare a delimiter at the beginning. Here is a sample to do it:

```
DECLARE @Delimiter VARCHAR(40)
SET @Delimiter = '|'
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST('<M>' + REPLACE([ColName], @Delimiter , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML)
        AS [ColName XML]
    FROM [Table]
)
SELECT
     [ColName XML].value('/M[1]', 'VARCHAR(40)') As [ID],
     [ColName XML].value('/M[2]', 'VARCHAR(40)') As [Key],
     [ColName XML].value('/M[3]', 'VARCHAR(40)') As [Date],
     [ColName XML].value('/M[4]', 'VARCHAR(40)') As [Company],
     [ColName XML].value('/M[5]', 'VARCHAR(40)') As [Owner]
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working pretty fine for me :)